# How, if it's reasonably possible, can you use .NET 7 Azure Functions in a Docker container (as opposed to .NET Core 3.1)?

Tags: docker, azure-functions, upgrade, .net-7.0

We've been using a Linux Dockerfile for a .NET Core 3.1 Azure Functions app.  It starts like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.0 AS base
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
```

Now we're looking to upgrade to .NET 7 - ***if*** Azure Functions is fairly compatible with it, including in Docker containers.  (In the past, I think Azure Functions has lagged in compatibility at least a time or two with .NET upgrades.)  Upgrading the Functions app to .NET 7 without changing the Dockerfile, we get this error:

```
error MSB3971: The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v7.0" were not found.
```

So I tried upgrading the Dockerfile.  When trying to create a new, temporary Functions project in Visual Studio, to get it to generate a starter Dockerfile for me, I see that only up to .NET 6 is on the list of options:

[image]

So that doesn't appear to work, and if anything, it indicates that Azure Functions is probably not ready for .NET 7 yet.  But looking [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk), I see an SDK version 7 image, and looking [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions-dotnet), I see a Functions version 4 image.  So then this is what I tried:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:4 AS base
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
```

Now I'm getting this error:

```
error : You must install or update .NET to run this application. [/src/<folder>/<project name>.csproj]
```

Is Azure Functions just not ready yet, for .NET 7 and/or a Linux Docker container?  If it is ready, how do you make this transition from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 7?

Comment: Try to switch your base image to `mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4`. According to the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#supported-versions), dotnet 7 is only available in an isolated function.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment Thank you!  It looks like it's still having trouble though, whether I use the 6.0 SDK or 7.0 SDK.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-7-comes-to-azure-functions/

Comment: @peinearydevelopment That sounds like it's still in preview, mixing AF, .NET 7, and Docker like that.  If so, then that's probably where I'd be willing to draw the line with this for now.  Do you want to post that as an answer?